# What date format is this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, date

I have a web service returning JSON data with some date fields but I couldn't recognize the date format to parse this date field.

```
2010-11-05TNov:10:1288995006 UTC
2010-10-28TOct:37:1288301863 UTC
2010-10-05TOct:33:1286314434 UTC
```

Comment: What has this got to do with Java? You know that Java and Javascript are completely unrelated languages, yes?

Comment: It's a Android project and I need to parse it with SimpleDateFormat, hence the java tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a quite weird timestamp, isn't it.

yyyy[-]mm[-]dd"T"hh":"mm":"ss.nnnnnn"Z" is an ISO standard date format (ISO 8601), which is similar to what appears in the first field of that... but it has what appear to be three field groups, holding what appear to be:

yyyy-mm-dd"T"MMM:??:POSIX-TIMESTAMP UTC

The current time being 1292563122, those would appear to have been generated 3,568,116 seconds (or approximately 41 days) ago.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As @The MYNN points out, the first timestamp's epoch matches the text timestamp with the exception of the hours field.  It definitely looks like this is a software bug somewhere.  The good news?  Whatever data this software did this to can be fixed by reading the UNIX timestamp and regenerating the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

The first epoch (1288995006) translates to

> Fri, 05 Nov 2010 22:10:06 GMT

Seems, somebody obfuscated or messed up the human readable month part - `22` would make more
sense than `Nov`. If you care about the date, I'd suggest you go with the epoch.

Sidenote:

> If a date and a time are displayed on the same line, then always write the date in front of the time. If a date and a time value are stored together in a single data field, then ISO 8601 suggests that they should be separated by a latin capital letter *T*, as in 19951231T235959.

- http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking the wrong people.  You should really be asking whoever is responsible for creating the web service where there documentation is and / or what format the timestamps are *supposed* to be.

(FWIW - I agree with the consensus that the timestamp format is probably erroneous.)

Comment: Agree, but I wanted to be sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything.  Even if you are, the service **should** be documented.